# SQL subquery getting multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I have a query like this, where my sub query is fetching multiple rows.

```
    SELECT TOOL.ANUM,
       ASSET.ID,
       ASSET.DESCRIPTION,
       TOOL.DATE,
  (SELECT CASE frequnit
              WHEN 'WEEKS' THEN finish+(frequency*7)
              WHEN 'MONTHS' THEN add_months(finish, pfrequency)
              WHEN 'YEARS' THEN add_months(finish, (frequency * 12))
              ELSE actfinish+pluscfrequency
          END AS frequency
   FROM workorder
   WHERE worktype = 'CAL'
     AND pmnum IS NOT NULL
     AND assetnum = '6847'
     AND actfinish <
       (SELECT actfinish
        FROM workorder
        WHERE wonum = '2354850')) freq,
FROM tool,
     Asset
LEFT JOIN PM ON asset.num = pm.num
AND PM.status = 'ACV'
WHERE asset.anum = tool.anum
  AND tool.wo = '2354850'
ORDER BY tool.anum
```

My sub query results are:

```
SELECT wnum,finish
CASE frequnit
                  WHEN 'WEEKS' THEN finish+(frequency*7)
                  WHEN 'MONTHS' THEN add_months(finish, pfrequency)
                  WHEN 'YEARS' THEN add_months(finish, (frequency * 12))
                  ELSE actfinish+pluscfrequency
              END AS frequency
       FROM workorder
       WHERE worktype = 'CAL'
         AND pmnum IS NOT NULL
         AND assetnum = '6847'
         AND actfinish <
           (SELECT actfinish
            FROM workorder
            WHERE wonum = '2354850')

wnum    finish     frequency
10003   12-NOV-15  13-DEC-2015
10004   14-DEC-15  15-DEC-2015
```

But I need the freq value for max(finish) in the sub query. I am able to get this by using rownum as follows:

```
select * from (subquery order by finish ) where rownum=1;
```

But I am not supposed to use the above one as I am referring one of the main query column in the sub query

assetnum = '6847'(assetnum = TOOL.ANUM)

Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the max, how about using this?

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT MAX(CASE frequnit
                     WHEN 'WEEKS' THEN finish+(frequency*7)
                     WHEN 'MONTHS' THEN add_months(finish, pfrequency)
                     WHEN 'YEARS' THEN add_months(finish, (frequency * 12))
                     ELSE actfinish+pluscfrequency
                   END) AS frequency
        FROM workorder
        WHERE worktype = 'CAL' AND
              pmnum IS NOT NULL AND
              assetnum = '6847' AND
              actfinish < (SELECT actfinish FROM workorder WHERE wonum = '2354850')
       ) freq,
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks Linoff. I need the freq value for max(finish) but not for max(finish+ freuency).